# Cannot install an extension in Visual Studio 2019 due to missing references

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

How do I fix these issues? Where do I need to download?

> C# Code Analyzer (Roslyn)
>
> This extension cannot be installed because
> the following references are missing:
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler

> ErrorProne.NET.Structs
>
> This extension cannot be installed because the
> following references are missing:
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageService

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem with both extensions and VS2019.

- [Roslyn](https://github.com/microsoft/RoslynClrHeapAllocationAnalyzer/issues/68) has a fix with versions 2.0 and there is also a work-around that you might try.
- [ErrorProne](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SergeyTeplyakov.EPNS01&ssr=false#qna) has a possible fix in its GitHub but it does not look to be release as an extension.  There is a work-around submitted by a user.

For `Roslyn`, if the new extension does not work, declare the dependency in `extension.vsixmanifest` and/or `catalog.json`.

```xml
<Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices" Version="[15.0.25904.2,)" DisplayName="C# and Visual Basic" />
```

For `ErrorProne`, try to add the following to a `Directory.Build.props` file:

```xml
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ErrorProne.NET.Structs" Version="0.3.0-beta.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Another `ErrorProne` work-around is to download the `vsix` from marketplace and modify two files: `extension.vsixmanifest` and `catalog.json`by replacing `[15.0,16.0)` with `[15.0,17.0)`

Comment: Where do I find any of the two, extension.vsixmanifest / catalog.json?

Comment: Check if you have them in your project.

Comment: Do I have to search through the files or seach inside visual studio?

Comment: Search in windows explorer inside your project folder.  Did you try getting the nuget? Or restore?

Comment: Well I searched in the internet for Nuget Restore and all I found is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/nuget-update), but there isn't any "Extensions and Updates" options in mine. (Visual Studio 2019, Windows)

@eglease

Comment: Can you open your NuGet manager in VS and check what is installed?

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/nuget-faq

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237228/discussion-between-richard-manansala-and-eglease).

Answer (score 0):

This should be an issue from the extension itself(some configurations not set, some prerequisites not add…). As you can see, the `C# Code Analyzer (Roslyn)` extension => last updated [4/8/2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AustinLuo.CCodeAnalyzerRoslyn), and the `ErrorProne.NET.Structs` extension => last updated [5/3/2018](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SergeyTeplyakov.EPNS01&ssr=false#overview).

Solution should be from extension side, and need to be fixed by author. Instead, you may try to install and use NuGet packages, NuGet packages seem work well. NuGet package for [C# Code Analyzer (Roslyn)/UDNZ.Roslyn.Analyzer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UDNZ.Roslyn.Analyzer), and [ErrorProne.NET.Structs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ErrorProne.NET.Structs/0.4.0-beta.1).